# Updating row numbers of a TableView in a Database when using 'move' with Appcelerator

Tags: ios, sqlite, tableview, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I've got a table view with an edit function on, and I can drag my rows up and down and change their position.

This works fine and I have a little SQL function which update the position ID of the row that moves.

The problem I'm having is that it won't update the other rows at the same time.
How do I do this?

For example, we start with this.....

Position 1: Row1
Position 2: Row2
Position 3: Row3
Position 4: Row4

You move Row4 to Position 2 and it updates using my script below to the correct one. The issue is Row2 then drops to Position 3 and Row3 drops to position 4, but they obviously don't change their position_id.

Here is my code on the 'move' listener

```
tableView.addEventListener('move', function(e) {

var newRow = e.row.row + 1;

Ti.API.info(e.rowData.speciesID + ' ' + e.rowData.speciesName + ' moved to position ' + newRow);


// update the order number
var db3 = Ti.Database.open('myDB');
db3.execute('UPDATE tour SET position_id=? WHERE tourItemID=?',newRow,e.rowData.speciesID);

db3.close();   });
```

Any suggestions on what i can do to update all the rows to the correct 'position_id'?

Running latest Titanium on iOS 8.2

Simon

Comment: can i ask why you want to update them?

Comment: Yes @AaronSaunders, so, it is for a tour of a theme park. The user select the things they want to visit during their day. Then, on the edit screen they can change the order in which they want to visit the various amusements. Want we want to achieve by moving the row, is a dynamic update of the on board DB to get the correct 'new' order of the tour, so when the user clicks the next button, their tour begins and everything loads in the correct order. Make sense?

Comment: yeah, makes sense.. i would keep the id/order i a separate table, because it looks like you will be doing a bunch of table updates every time the move items in the  table? Or don't update the order in the db until they go to the next page